# 301 redirect non-www and www to new domain but exclude homepage/root

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

**olddomain.com** has some toxic link pointing to it..
i would like to redirect www and non-www pages to **newdomain.com**. 
non-www redirect is not working..
root should not be redirected to **newdomain.com**.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# www homepage redirect
RedirectPermanent olddomain.com http://www.olddomain.com

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$ [NC]
#if not root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$ [NC]
#redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just this rule will be enough:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!css-images/).+)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

By using `.+` it will **not redirect** home page.

Comment: This works great!  I just found out i need one "css-images/" folder that should not be redirected to www.newdomain.com. Is there a way of making that exception?